# jQuery: "this.cloneNode is not a function" when included on a page with Prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, prototypejs

I'm trying to use jQuery in a bookmarklet, which means I don't have control of the page into which the JavaScript will be inserted.  From what I've read of [noConflict](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery.noConflict), it requires that jQuery be inserted first.  In the case of a bookmarklet, just the opposite is true.

So - does anyone have any suggestions on whether or not this is possible?  I've found it works except on pages that are using prototype.js.  On those pages, when I try to use the jQuery UI library, I get the error "this.cloneNode is not a function" in the bowels of jQuery, presumably because something in prototype is mucking with it.

Any help/advice would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean "I don't have control of the page into which the JavaScript will be inserted". If you have the ability to insert javascript on the page then you also have control of the page.

Comment: Do you plan on having the entire jQuery library embedded in your bookmarklet or will you add it to the page with a dynamic script tag?

Comment: Can you post the bookmarklet in question, or better yet, a simple test case that demonstrates the problem of using JQuery in a bookmarklet on a page using prototype?

Comment: @crescentfish - I'm using a dynamic script tag
@patrick - you can grab it here: http://www.wishpot.com/public/tools/buttons.aspx (choose "manual steps") and then click it on any product at anthropologie.com .

Answer (score 1):

noConflict has to be called after jQuery is included, and before some other library is included. So it's fine to include jQuery last, and then call noConflict -- it should then return the $ variable to whatever it was before jQuery was included.

It's sort of pain.  Your bookmarklet needs to:

```
if(!jQuery) {
    include_jQuery();
    var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
} else {
    var $ = jQuery;
}
// do things with $
```

So as to avoid wrecking the page if it already had jQuery.

Comment: That's what I'm doing.  In fact, I'm not even assigning or using $, I'm doing something like var myCustomVar = jQuery.noConflict(); and using that to prevent stomping on the rest of the page.  

My issue is that jQuery throws an error on cloneNode, which I think is being affected by prototype.